# Why does a public method in a thread not resolve in onCreate?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

App overview: a simpler server listening on a port for connections. To each client that connects to that port, it sends the GPS NMEA strings as they come out of the GPS chip.

So onCreate starts a single new thread that listens at the port. For each connection, this listener thread spins off another new thread. Each of those threads currently just spits out a "still connected" message every two seconds. This part all works, I can set up a couple telnet sessions and connect, all goes as expected. All of the location stuff is working in this code also; it properly updates the screen with correct and changing GPS info.

I want to register a single Nmealistener, and then have it dispatch that string to each thread serving a connection. However, socketListenerThread.MasterDispatchNmeaMessage(nmea) will not resolve inside addNmeaListener. (It won't resolve just outside of it, either.) the addNmeaListener doesn't seem to have an issue, if I have it just dump messages via Log.d it will happily do that.

Within the socketListenerThread class the method MasterDispatchNmeaMessage is also marked as "never called".

**So what is preventing MasterDispatchNmeaMessage from becoming resolved?**

For those not familiar, a sample NMEA string looks like this:

```
$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47
```

They come in bursts, probably averaging five to ten lines a second on Samsung S4 I'm testing with.

Additional note: I'm targeting API 22. Past that, much more permission checking comes into play for the location classes. So I want to get all of this actually working before adding on the new permission checks to have it compliant with the latest libraries.

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
static final String TAG = "GPSOverWiFi";
static final int LISTENING_PORT = 8085;

private TextView latitudeField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

Thread socketListenerThread;

TextView info, infoip;
ServerSocket serverSocket;
int gConnectionCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    latitudeField   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.liveLatitude);
    longitudeField  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.liveLongitude);
    infoip          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
    info            = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);

    // Get the GPS location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);



    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        latitudeField.setText("Location not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }

    infoip.setText("IP Addresss: " + getIpAddress() + ":" + LISTENING_PORT);
    socketListenerThread = new SocketListenerThread();
    socketListenerThread.start();

    //for giggles, it doesn't resolve here either, but this it needs to resolve a few lines down...
    //socketListenerThread.MasterDispatchNmeaMessage("asdf");

    locationManager.addNmeaListener(new GpsStatus.NmeaListener() {
        public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
            // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // socketListenerThread.MasterDispatchNmeaMessage errors here with 'can't resolve
            // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            socketListenerThread.MasterDispatchNmeaMessage(nmea);
            Log.d(TAG, "NMEA: " + nmea);
        }
    });
}



public class SocketListenerThread extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    ArrayList<EachConnectionThread> connectionThreads = new ArrayList<EachConnectionThread>();
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT);
            while (!isInterrupted()) { //You should handle interrupts in some way, so that the thread won't keep on forever if you exit the app.
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                gConnectionCount++;
                EachConnectionThread thread = new EachConnectionThread(socket);
                connectionThreads.add(thread);
                thread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void MasterDispatchNmeaMessage(String nmeaMessage) {
        for (EachConnectionThread serverThread : connectionThreads)
            serverThread.dispatchNmeaMessage(nmeaMessage);

    }
}


public class EachConnectionThread extends Thread {
    private Socket hostThreadSocket;

    EachConnectionThread(Socket socket) {
        hostThreadSocket = socket;
    }

    PrintStream printStream;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream;
            outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
            printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
            printStream.print("Connected\r\n");

            while(!printStream.checkError()) {
                SystemClock.sleep(2000);
                printStream.print("Still connected\r\n");
            }
            printStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            hostThreadSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        gConnectionCount--;
    }

    public void dispatchNmeaMessage(String nmeaString){
        printStream.print(nmeaString);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread socketListenerThread;` `Thread` does not have that method. Method resolution is made against the declared type (`Thread`), not the defined type `SocketListenerThread`

Comment: Have u considered using a service instead of an activity ,they both have context and can access gps and other comunication features, its not very good to bind all that logic to an activity

Comment: I have not considered a service. Time for more education. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the member variable declaration

```
Thread socketListenerThread;
```

to

```
SocketListenerThread socketListenerThread;
```

so you can access `SocketListenerThread` methods via the `socketListenerThread` instance.

Comment: laato, your change absolutely fixes the problem. It won't let me accept for another 8 minutes, so hold on.  I had not even thought about that variable's declaration changing the behavior in that way. Excellent lesson for today. You are a scholar and a gentleman. :)